# Inner Join using COUNT(*)

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am selecting the user's information from my MySQL database as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `$user_or_id` = ?
```

However, I would like to add an extra bit off information to the returned data. The extra bit of data is the total number of records in a table named 'Venues' where the rows' field, 'user_id' is the same as the 'id' field in the table, 'Users'.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong with the following query? Here is the error I am receiving:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*) FROM `Users` AS u INNER JOIN `Venues` AS v ON u.id =
>   v.user_id WHERE u.id = '' at line 1

```
SELECT u.*, v.count(*) FROM `Users` AS u INNER JOIN `Venues` AS v ON u.id = v.user_id WHERE u.$user_or_id = ?
```

Comment: probably `count(v.*)` (if even possible).

Comment: you have to use GROUP BY statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(v.*) FROM `Users` AS u INNER JOIN `Venues` AS v ON u.id = v.user_id WHERE u.$user_or_id = ?
```

`COUNT` is a MySQL function, not a member of table `v`. Pass it an argument representing what you want to count-- in this case, `v`'s rows.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `COUNT(v.*)`. Otherwise it's interpreted as "function count inside table V", which isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `count(*)` instead of `v.count(*)`.